# Private and Secure Files on Amazon S3 Storage with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just wanted to ask if anyone could give me a tip to get private and secure files on S3 accessible only to logged in users or when the business logic wants them to be accessible. Here is the scenario...

> A PHP Web application to enter billing details which generates a PDF
>   invoice on the fly and uploads it to the S3 bucket. (It actually
>   doesn't always generate and upload - only when the user wants to print or
>   download it - the code generates a pdf - uploads it to S3 and gets
>   back the url or the file accordingly)

Now, the file is accessible to anyone who has the url to the file on S3 bucket. I wanted to limit the file access in such a way that people who are not even logged in can get the file only after lets say answering a secret question etc.

Is generating a signed url which is valid for a small time the only answer here or am I looking at other possibilities also? Also, can we generate signed url's directly from S3 or do we need to do it through cloudfront?

Do suggest me a direction to research further... Thanks!

Comment: Access Control List, or Query String Authentication sound like possibilites

Comment: I have tried the query string authentication and yes - it sorta works...

Answer (score 0):

This might help? [Amazon CloudFront Private Content](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/09/27/amazon-cloudfront-announces-private-content-support-in-AWS-Console/)

I would assume you will need to setup a [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/ExerciseOverview.html) to ensure your user's credentials are verified and valid to keep the content "private".

Comment: The scenario was securing the files which is solved by Private storage and then giving signed urls for download and printing the documents. Now the issue remains is attaching them and mailing them to the user securely...

Comment: @foxybagga Mailing them.. as in snail mail?

Comment: Well, I mean emailing them. Lets say an administrator wanted to send an invoice to the user, how would he send it - if he sent across a signed link - it would just expire.

Comment: @foxybagga I'm not sure Amazon S3 would work for what you are intending to purpose it to. Usually this kind of thing would require a clickback link (per email is not secure) that links back to your webserver, which would either check their current authentication status, or passthrough if they are logged in already. The document you are requiring to be secure could be auto-generated by your webserver and really not need stored anywhere if its dynamic. I'm not sure if your functional specification *requires* S3 VPC. I would go without if not.

Comment: Ah thanks for reminding me - what I can do is send a link to a page on my webserver and ask the user to authenticate and download the file probably with the date of birth etc...

Answer (score 0):

This post https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/generate-expiring-amazon-s3-link/ can help you. Don't forget to check out the comments as well.

***** EDIT**

### Generate Expiring Amazon S3 Link

You don't have to make files on Amazon S3 public (they aren't by default). But you can generate special keys to allow access to private files. These keys are passed through the URL and can be made to expire.

```
<?php 

    if( !function_exists( 'el_crypto_hmacSHA1' ) ) {
        function el_crypto_hmacSHA1($key, $data, $blocksize = 64) {
                if (strlen($key) > $blocksize) $key = pack('H*', sha1($key));
                $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
                $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
                $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
                $hmac = pack( 'H*', sha1(
                ($key ^ $opad) . pack( 'H*', sha1(
                    ($key ^ $ipad) . $data
                ))
            ));
                return base64_encode($hmac);
        }
    }

    if(!function_exists('el_s3_getTemporaryLink')){

        function el_s3_getTemporaryLink($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $path, $expires = 5) {
            // Calculate expiry time
            $expires = time() + intval(floatval($expires) * 60);
            // Fix the path; encode and sanitize
            $path = str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($path = ltrim($path, '/')));
            // Path for signature starts with the bucket
            $signpath = '/'. $bucket .'/'. $path;
            // S3 friendly string to sign
            $signsz = implode("\n", $pieces = array('GET', null, null, $expires, $signpath));
            // Calculate the hash
            $signature = el_crypto_hmacSHA1($secretKey, $signsz);
            // Glue the URL ...
            $url = sprintf('http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s', $bucket, $path);
            // ... to the query string ...
            $qs = http_build_query($pieces = array(
                'AWSAccessKeyId' => $accessKey,
                'Expires' => $expires,
                'Signature' => $signature,
            ));
            // ... and return the URL!
            return $url.'?'.$qs;
        }
    }
```

## Usage

```
<?php

    echo el_s3_getTemporaryLink('your-access-key', 'your-secret-key', 'bucket-name', '/path/to/file.mov');
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.